# method identify if a file is under SVN version control or not

Tags: java, svn

I want to add a file to SVN. I am doing it from a java code as below

```
ourClientManager.getWCClient().doAdd(file, false, false, true , true);
```

using [`SVNWCClient`](http://svnkit.com/kb/javadoc/org/tmatesoft/svn/core/wc/SVNWCClient.html).

the file is already there in svn, so i get an error "is already under version control".

Is there any method available which will say that the file is already there in svn...somehting like isAlreadyUnderVersionControl(file).

Comment: You could place your call within a try-catch block and catch the exception that is thrown if the file is already added to the repository.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the below code, and it seems to be working.

```
final SVNStatus info = ourClientManager.getStatusClient().doStatus(file, false); 
if (!info.isVersioned()) {
    //call doAdd
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with that library, but it sounds like the `doInfo()` method might tell you what you need (it throws an exception if the path is not under version control).